# How to reset MotionLayout to first ConstraintSet

Tags: android, animation, android-constraintlayout, android-motionlayout

I use a ViewPager have 3 pages. How to reset MotionLayout and re-run animation when a page is re-selected?

Currently, I call method `transitionToStart()` when a page replaced by another. But if user swipe back too quickly, animation `transitionToStart()` won't finish.

Is there a better method?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
    motionLayout.setTransition(R.id.transition);
    motionLayout.transitionToEnd();
    if (instant)
        motionLayout.setProgress(1);
```

You can manually set the progress by calling `.setProgress(0)` or `.setProgress(1)`

Based on `.setTransition(R.id.transition)` you can define start and end constraint (in case you have more than two constraintSets).